# How to correctly align an image inside a React Material ui Grid?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-grid-layout

I was working on a footer for my project.
I am using material UI grid for the footer so I wanted to add the logo at the bottom but I don't understand why it is having right padding (I guess it is padding, not sure).

ScreenShot ->
It's something like this. (Have blurred the logo for privacy reasons)
[image]

Code Footer.js React Compoennt ->

```
import React from "react";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
import Link from "@material-ui/core/Link";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";

import logoWhite from "../logos/logoWhite.png";

function Copyright() {
  return (
    <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">
      {"Copyright © "}
      <Link color="inherit" href="https://material-ui.com/">
        Your Website
      </Link>{" "}
      {new Date().getFullYear()}
      {"."}
    </Typography>
  );
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    minHeight: "100vh",
  },
  main: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  footer: {
    padding: theme.spacing(3, 2),
    marginTop: "auto",
    backgroundColor: "#312D2D",
    color: "white",
    height: 167,
  },
  footerGrid: {
    width: "20%",
    marginLeft: 40,
    marginTop: 35,
    pading:0,
    border: "2px solid red"
  },
  footerLogo: {
      minWidth: "50%",
      maxWidth: "60%",
      width: "auto",
      margin: "0 auto",
      backgroundColor: "pink"
  },
  footerGridLogo: {
      width: "fit-content",
      pading:0,
      borderRight: "1px solid white",
      margin:0,
      border: "4px solid green"
  }
}));

export default function Footer() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <footer className={classes.footer}>
        <Grid spacing={0} className={classes.footerGrid}>
          <Grid item className={classes.footerGridLogo}>
              <img
                src={logoWhite}
                alt="brandlogo"
                className=""
                className={classes.footerLogo}
              />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </footer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Wanted it to look something like this ->
[image]

Comment: @NearHuscarl It doesn't seem to be working still.

Comment: in your `footerGridLogo` style, try center align image by setting the display to flex and justify-content to center.

Comment: okay that kinda worked, but the grid doesn't wrap around the logo ;-(

Comment: I change the `width` in `footerGrid` style to `fit-content`, is [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-sea-q4xk9?file=/index.js) what you want?

Comment: yup got it thanks!

Answer (score 0):

add this inline styling inside the Grid item tag style={{display:'flex',justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for you answer , Please make sure to add additional information , read more about [good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and the proper usage of [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) .